# Module Import Error with Nosetests and Tox

Tags: python-3.6, importerror, nose, tox

In my project, I am using tox with nosetests. Using PyCharm, my tox pipeline was passing completely including all the tests. When I execute tox on a Ubuntu18.04 container with python3, it gives me the following error:

> ImportError: No module named 'my_project'

leading to the following error at the end:

> ERROR: InvocationError for command /.tox/py36/bin/nosetests (exited with code 1)

`my_project` is the name of the module I am testing and the directory structure looks like this under `/`, the root dir from which I am executing `tox`:

- my_project/
- tests/
- tox.ini
- setup.cfg
- other files

My tox.ini looks as follows:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36

[testenv]
commands = python3 setup.py build
           nosetests
deps = -r{toxinidir}/test-requirements.txt
```

I have tried to provide the path to project in different ways to nosetests command but none of that works. One line that interests me is in the initial output of `tox`:

> py36 installed: my_project @ file:///.tox/.tmp/package/1/my_project-0.4.post52.dev256143400.zip,

which leads me to think if this is the reason that nosetests does not find my_project.
For details, the stack trace for the error is as follows:

> ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named 'my_project')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
>       raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
>   File "/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
>       addr.filename, addr.module)
>   File "/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
>       return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
>   File "/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 79, in importFromDir
>       fh, filename, desc = find_module(part, path)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No module named 'my_project'

Comment: Is there a `__init__.py` file in the `my_project` directory ?

Comment: Yes there is an `__init__.py` in `my_project/`.

Comment: The issue is still unresolved despite several attempts. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible offenders.

(1) `python3 setup.py build` should not exist in the `commands` section.

```
# the build command is redundant, there is a special option for this. 
commands = python3 setup.py build
           nosetests
# The install command with it's default
install_command=python -m pip install {opts} {packages}(ARGV)
deps = -r{toxinidir}/test-requirements.txt
```

(2) And with Pycharm you might have added your project as a `sources root` (right click folder > mark directory as > sources root). Or configured it otherwise (PATH variable perhaps?) that makes `my_project` available in context to running it in **Pycharm**? This should not happen inside tox though, unless you have whitelist externals or sitepackages turned to True..

So when installed on a container this link does not exist.

(3) I can't help but notice the abscence of a `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`. Files used to install `my_project`. E.g. run this command locally and debug your installation if it doesn't work:

```
pip install .
```